# How to set the initial value of a multidimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

2DI need to use a two-dimensional array of doubles to store grades. The first dimension of the array will represents each student while the second dimension represents the grade for each assignment. The maximum number of assignments for any course is provided when the course is created. I need to make it so that grades that have not been assigned are given an initial value of -1

I know that for single arrays you can do this

```
double[] grade = new double[10];
for (double i = 0; i < size; i++) {
array[i] = -1;
}
```

How would I do it for a 2D array?

Comment: Add an inner loop in it so you can use the X-Y coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    double[][] grade = new double[10][10];
    for (double[] e : grade) {
        Arrays.fill(e, -1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First all, you can't do this

```
double[] grade = new int[10];
```

double[] and int[] are incompatible types.

To declare a 2D array just use two sets of square brackets

```
double[][] grade = new double[10][10];
```

This will give you a total of 100 indices, max index being [9][9], and min[0][0].

To iterate through the array you use a nested loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){         // iterates each student
    for (int j = 0; j < grade[i].length; j++){  // iterates each grade
        // do something with grade[i][j]
    }
}
```